# Angular's nativeElement's offsetWidth is 0

Tags: javascript, angular, dom, angular7

I've tried to get offset data of the component in my angular app as below.

```
this.el.nativeElement.offsetWidth
```

But it is returning `0` if I don't pass it's css property as below.

```
this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, 'position', 'fixed');
```

it is working as I want.returning real value of the native component.But
I don't want to change the `position` property.

Do you suggest me any solution to get current offset data like offsetWidth etc..
you can work on [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hxr5n4).

Comment: Is the object visible on the page? If not, measurements will always return 0. Maybe setting position is making it visible

Comment: yeah it is visible. @JuanMendes

Comment: you need to use @ViewChild, you can check example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-behxcv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-element%2Fmy-element.component.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because the component is an inline element by default. You can change its `display` style attribute to `block` or `inline-block` to get the correct size in code:

```
:host {
  display: block; /* or display: inline-block; */
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lesd6h?file=src/app/my-element/my-element.component.css) for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

Some times the element might not have reference to the DOM object. Try doing change detection to refresh the reference. Sorry I am not able to comment.

import ChangeDetectorRef in the constructor

```
constructor(private changeDetect: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

@ViewChild('splashScreen') el: ElementRef;

getOffSetWidth() {
    // run change detection
    this.changeDetect.detectChanges();
    // And then try getting the offset
    const offsetWidth = this.el.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
    return offsetWidth; 
}
```